# Failed to fetch when I thy to upload file to S3 use JS Vue

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-s3

I try to upload file to my s3 bucket use this library https://github.com/Fausto95/aws-s3 and I get this error in the console:

[image]

this is code of component:

```
<template>
  <input type="file" @change="uploadFile(fieldName, $event.target.files)"/>
</template>

<script>
import S3 from 'aws-s3';

export default {
  computed: {
    config() {
      return {
        bucketName: 'in-converter-bucket',
        dirName: '', /* optional */
        region: 'eu-west-2',
        accessKeyId: 'AKIAZSUESKSZVZTI55PV',
        secretAccessKey: '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',
        s3Url: 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/in-converter-bucket?region=us-west-2&tab=objects', /* optional */
      }
    },
    S3Client() {
      return new S3(this.config);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadFile(fieldName, files) {
      let file = files[0]
      this.S3Client
      .uploadFile(file, '324')
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
  },
  props: ['fieldName', 'obj']
}

</script>
```

Any help will be very useful

Comment: Have you setup [cors for your bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)?

Comment: Thanks for comment, I don't know what is it. I will be reading about it.

Comment: I added this json to Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)

Comment: [
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]

Comment: But it still don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were three problems:

First: I didn't add CORS, something like this:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "HEAD",
        "GET",
        "DELETE"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Second I didn't add Bucket policy, something like this:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "http referer policy example",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Allow admins to put and delete objects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::658481773507:user/Admin"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::js-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::js-bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {}
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Allow anyone to get objects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::js-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::js-bucket/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

And I mixed up region, I wrote: eu-west-2, but I use: us-west-2;